# Short exact sequence and the order of groups

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence

Given a short exact sequence
$$1 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{\phi} B \xrightarrow{\psi} C \rightarrow 1, $$
what can I say about the relationships between the order of the groups $A, B$ and $C$?
This is what I came up with:
since $1 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{\phi} B \xrightarrow{\psi} C \rightarrow 1$ is exact, $\phi$ is injective and $\psi$ is surjective. Since $\phi$ is injective, every element $x \in A$ will map to one element in $B$. This means that the order of group $A$ is lesser than or equal to the order of $B$. Since $\psi$ is surjective, there is an element $x \in B$ for every $y \in C$ with $\psi(x) = y$. This means that the order of $B$ is greater than or equal to the order of $C$. So from this follows:
$$|A| \leq |B| \geq |C|,$$
but I don't know if this is right.

Comment: It just presents $C$ as $B/A$.  Use Lagrange (if everything is finite).

Comment: @Randall so does this mean that not only $|A| \leq |B| \geq |C|$ but also $|C| = |B/A|$?

Comment: @Randall and how exactly does this follow from Lagrange theorem?

Comment: If everything is finite, $|C| = |B/A| = |B|/|A|$.  So, $|B| = |A| \times |C|$.

Comment: It might be clearer to say it follows from the usual proof of Lagrange, rather than the statement.The usual proof is that the cosets of a subgroup $A$ form a partition of the group $B$ into parts of equal size $|A|$. The number of cosets is, by definition, $|B/A|$. So $|B|=|A||B/A|$.

Comment: @verret is saying it better.

Comment: @verret this makes sense, but is the inequality I stated above also right, or is that wrong?

Comment: Are you asking whether $|B|=|A||C|$ implies $|A|\leq |B|\geq |C|$?

Comment: @verret yes indeed

Comment: @PhillipJones  why does the inequality matter when you have MUCH more precise information from $|B| = |A| \times |C|$?

Answer (score 1):

See that means $A$ is embedded in $B$ as a subgroup. So  $|A|\leq |B|$ and $C$ is an image of $B$ so, $|C|\leq |B|$. Your conclusion is correct.